Svelte perform action on a component from another component
I created a svelte modal component based on this example https://svelte.dev/examples/modal
However, since I did not want the close button coming from the modal, I removed it. The code is a below
<script lang="ts">
    export let showModal: boolean; // boolean

    let dialog: HTMLDialogElement; // HTMLDialogElement

    $: if (dialog && showModal) dialog.showModal();
</script>

<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events a11y-no-noninteractive-element-interactions -->
<dialog
    bind:this={dialog}
    on:close={() => (showModal = false)}
    on:click|self={() => dialog.close()}
    class="backdrop:bg-slate-500/30 backdrop:dark:bg-slate-200/10"
>
    <slot />
</dialog>


I am using this Modal in another component as below
<script lang="ts">
import Modal from '$lib/components/Modal.svelte';
let showModal = false;
</script>

<button on:click={() => (showModal = true)}> OPEN MODAL </button>

<Modal bind:showModal >

  <div>cmodal content blah blah blah </div>

  <button on:click={() => (showModal = false)}> CLOSE MODAL</button>

</Modal>

Modal opens without any issues whin i click the "OPEN MODAL" button but it does not close when I click "CLOSE MODAL" button! (it closes on clicking the backdrop as expected)
What I am doing wrong? How do close the modal from within the modal?

After some debugging it seems that your on:close in the Modal.svelte is not being called. I'm going to try and see if I can fix it

It does correctly update the showModal property when clicking the button and it does get reflected by Modal.svelte. It seems the reactive statement isn't properly being applied

The on:click only applies when the modal is being clicked directly, and doesnt fire when the slot is being clicked.

The issue is quite simple but weird:

The on:click only gets triggered when something inside the same file is being clicked, which your slot is technically not. This means that on:click never gets the chance to close the modal when you click the close button.
Because on:click is the only function that actually calls .close() on your modal and it never gets fired, your modal can never be closed.
The solution:
Update the reactivity statement:

  $: {
    if (dialog) {
      if (showModal) {
        dialog.showModal();
      } else {
        dialog.close();
      }
    }
  }

It is quite simple:
This statement checks if the dialog is defined and then shows/closes the modal depending on the state of showModal.

It worked! Thanks.
